# Format decimal to string in swift with correct rounding

Tags: swift

I've been using the following way to format decimals to strings:

`NSString(format: "%\(0.2)f", DECIMAL)`

However I noticed something odd which is that `1.025` rounds to `1.02` where as `1.026` rounds to `1.03`.  Is this correct behavior?

I remember in math we always would round up at `.5`.  Is this an expected behavior I've never noticed?  Or is there a better way to do this.

[image]

**NIST** rounding rules are as such: (http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP811/appenB.html#B.7.2)

> B.7.2 Rounding converted numerical values of quantities
>
> The use of the factors given in Secs. B.8 and B.9 to convert values of
>   quantities was demonstrated in Sec. B.3. In most cases the product of
>   the unconverted numerical value and the factor will be a numerical
>   value with a number of digits that exceeds the number of significant
>   digits (see Sec. 7.9) of the unconverted numerical value. Proper
>   conversion procedure requires rounding this converted numerical value
>   to the number of significant digits that is consistent with the
>   maximum possible rounding error of the unconverted numerical value.
>
> Example:  To express the value l = 36 ftin meters, use the factor
>   3.048 E-01 from Sec. B.8 or Sec. B.9 and write
>
> l = 36 ft × 0.3048 m/ft = 10.9728 m = 11.0 m. The final result, l =
>   11.0 m, is based on the following reasoning: The numerical value "36" has two significant digits, and thus a relative maximum possible
>   rounding error (abbreviated RE in this Guide for simplicity) of ±
>   0.5/36 = ± 1.4 % because it could have resulted from rounding the number 35.5, 36.5, or any number between 35.5 and 36.5. To be
>   consistent with this RE, the converted numerical value "10.9728" is
>   rounded to 11.0 or three significant digits because the number 11.0
>   has an RE of ± 0.05/11.0 = ± 0.45 %. Although this ± 0.45 % RE is
>   one-third of the ± 1.4 % RE of the unconverted numerical value "36,"
>   if the converted numerical value "10.9728" had been rounded to 11 or
>   two significant digits, information contained in the unconverted
>   numerical value "36" would have been lost. This is because the RE of
>   the numerical value "11" is ± 0.5/11 = ± 4.5 %, which is three times
>   the ± 1.4 % RE of the unconverted numerical value "36." This example
>   therefore shows that when selecting the number of digits to retain in
>   the numerical value of a converted quantity, one must often choose
>   between discarding information or providing unwarranted information.
>   Consideration of the end use of the converted value can often help one
>   decide which choice to make.
>
> Note: Consider that one had been told initially that the value l = 36
>   ft had been rounded to the nearest inch. Then in this case, since l is
>   known to within ± 1 in, the RE of the numerical value "36" is ± 1
>   in/(36 ft × 12 in/ft) = ± 0.23 %. Although this is less than the ±
>   0.45 % RE of the number 11.0, it is comparable to it. Therefore, the result l = 11.0 m is still given as the converted value. (Note that
>   the numerical value "10.97" would give excessive unwarranted
>   information because it has an RE that is one-fifth of ± 0.23 %.)

Comment: The format should be `"%0.2f"`, without the string interpolation.

Comment: The real problem is that the number 1.025 cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number, so `a` might be slightly less than 1.025. I am sure that this has been answered before somewhere.

Comment: Your examples don't match your screenshot, and they don't help making the question very clear...

Comment: @MartinR yep, check with [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). 1.025 is actually 1.024999976158142 thus it's rounded to 1.02 even if format is set correctly to "%0.2f".

Comment: @Jeef better use [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-SW16) where you can configure [Rounding Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-SW16).

Comment: Just FYI - [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)